# PlayN : add TriplePlay text field to a spefic position

Tags: playn, tripleplay

I have a simple background layer:

```
@Override
public void wasAdded() {
    super.wasAdded();

     Image bgImage = PlayN.assets().getImage("images/Welcome.png");
     ImageLayer bgLayer = graphics().createImageLayer(bgImage);
     layer.add(bgLayer);

     Image usernameButton =
     PlayN.assets().getImage("images/textField.png");
     ImageLayer usernameLayer =
     graphics().createImageLayer(usernameButton);
     usernameLayer.setTranslation(197, 337);
     layer.add(usernameLayer);

    }
}
```

And I would like to add a Text field element to a specific position (over the username image).

```
final Field field = new Field();
field.text.update("your name");
```

How can I achieve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to create an AbsoluteLayout root and add the group at the specific position:

```
_root = iface.createRoot(new AbsoluteLayout(), SimpleStyles.newSheet(), layer);
_root.setSize(width(), height());
Group group = new Group(new AbsoluteLayout()).add(AbsoluteLayout.at(new Field("username"), 197, 337));
_root.add(AbsoluteLayout.at(group, 0, 0));
```